# The simplest possible service-discovery with pyzmq?

Tags: python, networking, pyzmq

I'd like to be able to do something like this: [Python service discovery: Advertise a service across a local network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21089268/python-service-discovery-advertise-a-service-across-a-local-network)

But without the time.sleep() statements - everything should work out of the pyzmq event loop.

How could this be rewritten in the 0mq style?

EDIT0: This will need to run on Linux (Redhat + Ubuntu) and Windows. Possibly mac as well. Let's just say everything, including Raspberry pi.

Comment: What platform are you on?  Would you consider using something like https://code.google.com/p/pybonjour/ ?

Comment: Just edited to include that information.